# Trying to set up Grapics Tablet (Gaomon, Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, tablet, wacom

a while ago I bought this graphics tablet [Amazon link](https://smile.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B07HQDN7W6/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

I couldn't figure out how to get it to work then, but since I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22 I decided to give it another shot.

When I plug in the USB cable, Ubuntu does seem to recognize what's going on. Under settings, a tab for Wacom tablets shows up that isn't there otherwise. But when I go to that tab, it tells me that neither the tablet nor the stylus have been recognized.
To configure the stylus, it tells me to move it closer to the tablet, which doesn't seem to do anything.
There are no prompts to configure the tablet, only a link to the bluetooth settings. I'm guessing this is intended for bluetooth-operated tablets.

If anyone could help me out or give me a few pointers, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ubuntu desktop and server is *year.month*. Ubuntu Core is year only. Please do not confuse this very distinct products and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: you may need to install the digimend drivers (`digimend-dkms`) which are available from the Universe repository. I found some directions [here](https://www.davidrevoy.com/article870/review-gaomon-m10k-2018-graphic-tablet-on-linux-for-digital-painting) regarding other steps you may have to take to get it working